# Binding a value into an exsiting function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I am trying to pass an argument `single` into a preexisting function in javascript with `bind()`.

```
var connect = function(index) {
    console.log(this.single);
    ...
}

var connect_fn = connect;
connect_fn.bind({
    single: true
});

$(".box").each(connect_fn);
```

Unfortunately, in the `console.log()` `this.single` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind` returns a new function.

```
connect_fn = connect_fn.bind({
    single: true
});
```

Full example:

```
function test() {
    console.log(this.test);
}

test.bind({test: 'test'})();
```

Comment: Ok I see the problem when I use `bind()` I am losing the jquery behavior of `each()` passing a reference to the selector. How can I retain that? i.e. inside of `connect()` `this` is now just an object with `single = true`. I don't have a reference to the jQuery element any longer.

Comment: @Justin, The second argument passed to the function will be the element.

Comment: See my jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/2VXHJ/). Noticed how the console.log(this) does not include a jQuery reference to the object anymore. Without `bind()` $(this) is a reference to the jQuery element.